# Download created CSV file from custom directory

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, download

I create a PHP and ajax codes to create CSV file and download it when click a button. The PHP codes work fine, and for ajax I modify and set js codes according to [Handle file download from ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086162/handle-file-download-from-ajax-post) all works good. but the downloaded csv file is empty while the file in custom file is correct. I use this codes in custom wordpress plugin.

```
function _exe_export_vendor_products(){
 $current_user_id = esc_sql($_POST['c_user_id']);
 $arg = array(
 'limit' => 20,
 'author'    => $current_user_id
);
$product_list = wc_get_products($arg);

$title_array[] = array('ID', 'name', 'Price', 'SalePrice');

foreach($product_list as $_list){
$data_array[] = array($_list->get_id(), $_list->get_name(), $_list->get_price(), $_list->get_sale_price());
}
$final_array = array_merge($title_array, $data_array);

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tehran");
$current_date = date('Y-m-d-H-i');
$filename = "export-" . $current_user_id . "-" . $current_date . ".csv";
$f = fopen('https://sitename.com/export-import/' . $filename, 'w');
$delimiter=";";
foreach($final_array as $final_item){
  fputcsv($f, $final_item, $delimiter);
}
fseek($f, 0);
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8' );
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'";');
readfile($filename);
fclose($f);
}
```

and JS codes:

```
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: Ajax_object_dokan.ajax_url,
data:{
    action: '_dokan_export_vendor',
    c_user_id : current_user_id
},
xhrFields:{
    responseType: 'blob'
},
success: function(blob, status, xhr){
    var filename = "";
    var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
    if(disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1){
        var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
        var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
        if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
    }
    if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    } else {
        var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        if (filename) {
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            // safari doesn't support this yet
            if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                window.location.href = downloadUrl;
            } else {
                a.href = downloadUrl;
                a.download = filename;
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
            }
        } else {
            window.location.href = downloadUrl;
        }

        setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); }, 100); // cleanup
    }
    
}
});
```

I create file in `https://sitename.com/export-import/filename.csv` while the create tag `a` in JS has link to `https://sitename.com/59360c8b-22a5-462b-9d7e-240e54a0c094`.

How can I access to correct link to download file with ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

- You use `fopen()` to access a URL with `w` mode. It can't work. You can only access a URL for reading.
  Just use a path on the filesystem, for example:

```php
$f = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/export-import/' . $filename, 'w');
```

- You call `readfile()` with just the file name, not the full path.
- You call `readfile()` on the file before closing it. It may work but it's better to call `fclose()` first.
  And you don't need to call `fseek()`.
- You set the `Content-Encoding: UTF-8` header. That header is used to indicate compression (e.g. `gzip`), *not*
  the character encoding. Remove it.

Also note that you don't need AJAX to download a file. You can just submit a form. All that complicated JS code is unnecessary.

Comment: The problem was readfile(), there were not full path. Thanks.